Generic reducedness of geometric generic fibre
Let $f:X\to Y$ be a surjective morphism between two projective schemes over a  field of characteristic $p>0$. Also assume that $X$ is smooth,$Y$ smooth & irreducible and $f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$ (...so fibres connected by Stein).
I have a question about some points in Jason Starr's answer here:
Firstly as his example shows it may happen that the (geometric) generic fibre of $f$ is nowhere reduced.
But in first paragraph he mentioned a criterion by means of intersection numbers that the geometric generic fibre is generically reduced, namely that for any class of an ample divisor $A$ on $X$, and for any ample divisor class $B$ on $Y$, if the intersection number $A^{\text{dim}(X)-\text{dim}(Y)} \cdot  (f^*B)^{\text{dim}(Y)}$ (in the Chow ring) is prime to $p$, then the geometric generic fiber of $f$ is generically reduced.
Question: Could somebody give a reference discussing this result or sketch the involved ideas?

I think it is in an article that I wrote with Zhiyu Tian and Ruhong Zong.  I will try to find the precise source.

The reference is Proposition 5.2 of the following: http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.3495.pdf
